# the relation between the transitivity and intransitivity of a verb

Tags: syntax, transitivity

I had a problem with understanding the following question:
 Try to determine for each case how the 'intransitive' use relates to the transitive use and whether it reflects (i) an idiosyncratic property of the particular verb, (ii) a property of a wider semantic class of verbs, (iii) a property of the syntactic construction, (iv) a feature of a particular style or speech-act - or possibly some combination of these:

can someone please explain how to answer the question?

Comment: What are you having trouble with, in particular? "Do my homework for me" questions tend not to be very well-received here, but if you can explain what your confusion is, we may be able to help.

Comment: what does it mean the relation between the transitivity and intransitivity of a verb? does mean to mention the reason why is it used as intransitive? also, for the properties of the verb does it mean to explain the meaning of a certain verb in the sentence and its tense? that what I'm confused with. I don't really understand the question.

Comment: Yes, in this case it means "how and why is this verb being used with only a single argument here, when it usually needs more than that?"

Comment: I see. Now it's easier to understand. Thank you so much. but what does it mean the idiosyncratic property of a verb?

Comment: A great deal depends on the list of verbs supplied; I could think of lists that would convince anybody of any theory if they restricted their attention to them.